# How to call a method in my integration flow

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have created a method that reads a csv file and writes the data in a new csv file, I want to invoke that method in my integration flow, So basically I'm pulling a csv file from my FTP server with name FEFOexportBEY.csv and I want to generate a new file from that csv and call it finalBEY.csv, the customised method should do the writing but I want to invoke it in the flow after I poll the csv from FTP.
Below is the coding of the customised method and the flow integration, I found that this could be done using .handle but was not able to find the proper way. In my old project I was able to do this in xml config by creating a bean with the class name of the method and then injecting the method in the rout,now I'm using DSL and there should be a possible way if someone can help.

Method to handle

```
@Component
public class CSVToCSVNoQ {

public CSVToCSVNoQ() {
}

public void writeCSVfinal(String payload,@Header("new") String newCSV,@Header("old") String oldCsv) throws IOException {

    CSVReader reader = null;
    reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(oldCsv));
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(newCSV);

    //try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(newCSV), ',', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)) {
    try(CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(fileWriter,CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,
                                                        CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)){
        List<String[]> line;
        reader.readNext();
        reader.readNext();
        SimpleDateFormat from = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        SimpleDateFormat to = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy");

        line = reader.readAll();

        Iterator<String[]> itr = line.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()){
            String[] array = itr.next();
            if(array[0].equals("DET")) {
                // System.out.println("Change Format " + to.format(from.parse(array[5])));
                array[5] = to.format(from.parse(array[5]));
            }
        }

        while (itr.hasNext()){
            String[] array = itr.next();
            System.out.println("Line " + itr.next());
        }

        csvWriter.writeAll(line);
        csvWriter.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Integration flow on the inbound.

```
 public IntegrationFlow fileInboundFlowFromFTPServer(Branch myBranch) throws IOException {

    final FtpInboundChannelAdapterSpec sourceSpecFtp = Ftp.inboundAdapter(createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch))
            .preserveTimestamp(true)
          //.patternFilter("*.csv")
            .maxFetchSize(MAX_MESSAGES_PER_POLL)
            .remoteDirectory(myBranch.getFolderPath())
            .regexFilter("FEFOexport"+myBranch.getBranchCode()+".csv")
            .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
            .localDirectory(new File(myBranch.getBranchCode()))
            .temporaryFileSuffix(TEMPORARY_FILE_SUFFIX)

            /*.localFilenameExpression(new FunctionExpression<String>(s -> {
                final int fileTypeSepPos = s.lastIndexOf('.');
                return DateTimeFormatter
                        .ofPattern(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT_OF_FILES)
                        .withZone(ZoneId.of(TIMEZONE_UTC))
                        .format(Instant.now())
                        + "_"
                        + s.substring(0,fileTypeSepPos)
                        + s.substring(fileTypeSepPos);
            }))*/;

    // Poller definition
    final Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec> stockInboundPoller = endpointConfigurer -> endpointConfigurer
            .id("stockInboundPoller")
            .autoStartup(true)
            .poller(poller());

    IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(sourceSpecFtp, stockInboundPoller)

            .transform(File.class, p ->{
                // log step
                LOG1.info("flow=stockInboundFlowFromAFT, message=incoming file: " + p);
                return p;
            })

            .channel(CHANNEL_INTERMEDIATE_STAGE)
            .handle(m -> {
                try {
                    this.csvToCSVNoQ.writeCSVfinal("test", myBranch.getBranchCode() + "/final" + myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv", myBranch.getBranchCode() + "/FEFOexport" + myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv");
                    LOG1.info("Writing final file .csv " + m);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            })
            .get();

    return flow;
}
```

Old XML config

```
 <bean id="myBeanId" class="com.preparationforinterview.csvprocessing.CSVTOCSVNOQUT"/>


    <!--BEY routing-->
    <route>
        <from uri="ftp://XXXX@XXX.XXX.XX:21/ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/?fileName=FEFOexportBEY.csv"/>
        <log message="Level=INFO&amp;showBody=true&amp;showHeaders=true"/>
        <to uri="file:input"/>
        <bean ref="myBeanId" method="writeCSVfinal(output\finalBEY.csv,input\FEFOexportBEY.csv)"/>
        <bean ref="myBeanId" method="readCSVOrder(input\FEFOexportBEY.csv)"/>
        <log message="Inserting orders and details in the database from BEY"/>
        <to uri="ftp://XXXX@XXX.XXX.XX:21/ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/History/?autoCreate=true&amp"/>
    </route>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your method reference definition is fully wrong in that `.handle()`.

Anyway let's forget it for now!

On the other hand your `writeCSVfinal()` method signature is not so Messaging friendly. You have two arguments which from the invoker perspective are identical and you are going to have ambiguity because framework can't determine which one is about a `payload` from the request message.

But we still can achieve the goal with your method and the `.handle()` like this:

```
.handle(m -> this.cSVToCSVNoQ.writeCSVfinal(m.getPayload(), m.getHeaders().get(...)))
```

Or some other logic to really determine values for the method arguments.

Also keep in mind that your method returns `void`, therefore such a handler can be used only in the end of flow. There is just nothing as an output to be sent to the next channel in the chain.

Fully not clear how that your Camel code works.

Comment: Excuse my knowledge in spring integration, still learning it, so my writeCSVfinal() method takes first the new file location and name as string then second the old file location and name. It writes the new file based on the old one...this works smooth outside spring integration so I was trying to put it in a handle, what is the best way to create it so that it will be more friendly with messaging...

So what I understood from your help above is that I should pass the arguments in the .get(..), is there any example you can point me to so that I can reference it?@Artem Bilan

Comment: Please, read this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations. Id doesn't related to your issue, but at least it says that you can't have two arguments without particular annotation so framework won't understand which one is for `payload`.

Comment: If you say it works well outside of Spring Integration, then you just need to make yourself familiar with Spring Integration. Please, read Reference Manual from the beginning to determine what is Message, Handler and Channel between them. How request-reply works and what is arguments mapping. I don't know where you get your `new file location` and `old file location`, so, I just showed you what is a possible variant to call your method. You should determine for yourself what part of the request message carries respective information.

Comment: Sorry took time to work look into this again, I was able to get this sorted by adding headers on the method...I edit the code above ...the only issue I'm facing is if I have two server that I'm polling for new files and if one server receives a new file, it is being pulled to local and logically it should transform the new file to finalXXX.csv and sends it to remote, but what it is doing it is performing the method on all files that exist in my local folder and not the new one only...not sure what is the issue...trying to figure out ..@Artem Bilan